Book series with a character who is forgotten by everyone
I'm trying to find this book series I read in middle school with a character who no one could remember. He had a girlfriend later in the series who was blind and wore a bracelet with his name in Braille on it so she wouldn't forget him. At the end of one of the books he spreads himself so thin across reality he ceases to exist, to the point where his girlfriend can't remember and takes off the bracelet and leaves it behind.
I think there's also a character who is supposed to be a foil to him, having the opposite power to reel in everyone's attention.

Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please read our identification-request wiki and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] further details into the question. For example, when were you in middle school? Was this a middle-grade book, or aimed at a different age? What language is it in? Where was it set, e.g. a small town in Ohio or a large school in Tokyo? What time period was it set in? Did it have other fantasy/sci-fi elements, such as aliens or fae? Do you remember anything about the cover?

It was in english, and yeah, i do think it was either a middle school or ya book!

A character who is forgotten by everyone makes me think of Fin from The Map to Everywhere. I haven't read the whole series, so I'm not sure if the rest of it matches, but does that ring any bells for you?

Just checked it out, and nope, that isn't it.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

I think this could possibly be the Zeroes series, by Scott Westerfeld,  Margo Lanagan and Deborah Biancotti.
It deals with a group of teenagers born in the year 2000 (hence calling themselves the "zeroes") each of whom have a particular power. One of them, Thibault, is nicknamed "Anonymous" because people forget that he is present. In one case he nearly died when he was in hospital, because the doctors and nurses kept forgetting that he was there. He falls in love with another member of the Zeroes, Flicker, a blind girl whose superpower is that she can see through other people's eyes. In the second book in the series, Swarm, she wears a leather bracelet with his name written on it in braille to remind herself of his existence:

By reflex her fingers went to the bracelet around her right wrist.
Braille letters were punched into the band of leather. They settled
slowly into meaning.
T-H-I-B-A-U-L-T.

The leader of the group, Nate (nicknamed "Bellwether"), in contrast to Thibault, is extremely charismatic and has the ability to command everyone's attention.

Definitely. I thought of this one as soon as I saw the title.
